# Android draw outside the view

Tags: android, layout, view, android-studio

I would work with a piece of layout that isn't shown, the user must scroll to see what I have did. How can I do it? Can I join 2 different layout in one? I prefer to collocate item as I do with default layout. If it can help, I use Android studio. I prefer use elements without code, adding them from palette. An example :
[image]

Comment: You can use this by scroll listener , when it reaches at page end you can showe the layout or you can directly implement both layout into one scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different layout in main relative layout & whenever u want child layout just set visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a `ScrollView` for this. From the [documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

> Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display.

Comment: I added scrollView to RelativeLayout (now RelativeLayout is bigger because I set it to a bigger dimension of the view). It still not work, I can't scroll

Comment: Because you have to add the things you want to scroll to the scroll view, not the scroll view to the layout.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you for help. I can't put more then 1 item inside the scrollView

Comment: You need to put all of your items you want to scroll in a single layout.  Then put that layout in a scroll view.

Comment: @GabeSechan I did it but the item not shown entirely still not moving

Comment: Are you sure that the ScrollView completely encompasses the layout that you want to scroll? Also, make sure you're not using a ListView inside the ScrollView,